# I do not know how to build a SQL query correctly

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I work on my project using the sqlite database. In the project there is a chat, without channels, just 1 on 1. These are the tables:

```
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  firstName varchar(30),
  lastName varchar(50),
  email varchar(150),
  phone varchar(12),
  address varchar(255),
  photo varchar(255),
  hash varchar(255),
  token varchar(255)
)`);
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  lastMessage varchar(255)
)`);
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chatUser (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  idChat integer,
  idUser integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (idChat) REFERENCES chat(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)`);
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  idChat integer,
  idUser integer,
  text varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (idChat) REFERENCES chat(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)`);
```

In the `chatUser` table, I always add only two users (the current user and the user with which it is rewritten). I'm trying to make a query to get a list of the current user's chat (list should include name, photo, chat id of the person whom chatting with me and last message)

```
db.all(`
  SELECT chatUser.idChat,
         user.firstName,
         user.lastName,
         user.photo,
         chat.lastMessage
  FROM user, chatUser, chat
  WHERE user.id = chatUser.idUser
  AND chat.id = chatUser.idChat
  AND user.id != ?
`, [id], function(error, chats) {
  ...
}
```

Where **id - current user id**. This worked until I came from another user who, instead of one chat, displays two extra ones. Please help me build the query correctly.

Comment: What you're looking for a is a JOIN which joins two tables based on a column, i.e. the user id. Doing table1, table2, table3 unfortunately, isn't as effective. See; http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-inner-join/

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine the query is splited into two steps :

1. You have to select the chats for the current user
2. From the chats of the current user you can select the other users participating in the same chats

Bellow example for the current user equals 1 :

```
SELECT othersChatUser.idChat,
         user.firstName,
         user.lastName,
         user.photo,
         chat.lastMessage
  FROM 
    user, 
    chatUser as currentChatUser, 
    chatUser as othersChatUser, 
    chat
  WHERE currentChatUser.idUser = 1
  AND currentChatUser.idChat = othersChatUser.idChat
  AND user.id = othersChatUser.idUser
  AND user.id <> currentChatUser.idUser
  AND chat.id = othersChatUser.idChat;
```

The result of your query : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/37efd/1)